# appropriate data structure to implement in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm sorry if this is not well written question.

I'm retrieving sensory data records from hardware. There are many sensory data records and each of them have lines of hexadecimal bytes. The responses are received one at a time. It's a line of hexadecimal bytes and these are returned one line at a time. For example: It returns first line from 1st record and continues until the first record is finished. Then it moves to second record...
I need help with finding appropriate data structure in python.

Response

1st Record

02 00 20 00 01 15 01 67 40 09 6f 71

02 00 00 71 00 71 00 c0 00 00 01 00

02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cf 50 77 72

02 00 20 55 6e 69 74 20 53

2nd Record

03 00 20 00 03 07 01 67 40 23 6f 0f 01 00 00 0f
 01

03 00 c0 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cd 49 50
 4d

03 00 49 20 57 61 74 63 68

and so on until the last record

Comment: Appropriate for what?

Comment: Depends on how you use it, really.  That's also something that you decide.  We can't say just by looking at hex that there's a perfect datastructure for you.

Comment: 2d lists would probably work or 3d if you want to separate records

Comment: @NendoTaka Yes!! I want to separate the each records not each response line.

Comment: There are a lot of good data structures but for something simple a nested lists or a dictionary of lists would probably work

Comment: See [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad and opinion based so I had to flag, but here is one solution:

You can use a dictionary with the lines held in a list as values:

```
records = {}
records["1st Record"] = ["02 00 20 00 01 15 01 67 40 09 6f 71", "02 00 00 71 00 71 00 c0 00 00 01 00", "02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cf 50 77 72", "02 00 20 55 6e 69 74 20 53"]
records["2nd Record"] = ["03 00 20 00 03 07 01 67 40 23 6f 0f 01 00 00 0f 01", "03 00 c0 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cd 49 50 4d", "03 00 49 20 57 61 74 63 68"]
```

And so on. I can't see how you receive the values but i'm assuming you will do this along the lines of:

```
for record in data:
    records[record] = []
    for line in record:
        records[record] += [line]
```

In the end you have:

```
print(records)

>>> {'1st Record': ['02 00 20 00 01 15 01 67 40 09 6f 71', '02 00 00 71 00 71 00 c0 00 00 01 00', '02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cf 50 77 72', '02 00 20 55 6e 69 74 20 53'], '2nd Record': ['03 00 20 00 03 07 01 67 40 23 6f 0f 01 00 00 0f 01', '03 00 c0 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cd 49 50 4d', '03 00 49 20 57 61 74 63 68']}
```